# Can't format properly with AWK?

Tags: bash, awk

Does anyone know how to align the columns properly? I've spent so much time on it but when I make changes the rest of the columns fall out of alignment. It needs to be neatly aligned like the little table I drew below:

```
________________________________________________________
|Username| UID | GID |        Home        |    Shell   |
________________________________________________________
| root   | 0   | 0   |/root               |/bin/bash   |
| posgres| 120 | 125 |/var/lib/postgresql |/bin/bash   |
| student| 100 | 1000|/home/student       |/bin/bash   |
________________________________________________________


#!/bin/bash
echo "_________________________________________________________"
echo -e "| Username\t| UID\t| GID\t| Home\t| Shell\t\t|"
echo "---------------------------------------------------------"
awk 'BEGIN { FS=":" }
{ printf("\033[34m| %s\033[0m\t\t| %s\t| %s\t| %s\t| %s\t|\n", $1, $3, $4, $6, $7)
}' /etc/passwd | sed -n '/\/bin\/bash/p'
```

Comment: Usually the easiest is to not try and do the formatting in awk, but to pipe the output into the `column -t` command (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/column.1.html)

Comment: It's what our lecturer wanted. He is busy now though...

Comment: I would use HTML. There are some things which don't work well when purely character-based. The alignment of that table will most likely break if you try and send it through telnet/ssh as well.

Comment: hint: [sprintf](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) does not print, it just returns a formatted string.

Comment: Could you post the actual output you get when running this command?

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know how to align the columns properly?

> It's what our lecturer wanted.

Since it could be an assignment, I will share some hints instead of posting the working codes.

- First of all, awk can do the job of your `|sed`, you can save one process. For example `awk '/pattern/{print $1}`
- To build the table, you need to find out the longest value in each column before you really print the output. Because you need this value to decide the column width in your `printf` function. Read the doc of the `printf` function, you can pad the `%s`.
- You can read the lines you need and store each column in an array, e.g. `col1[1]=foo;col2[1]=bar; col1[2]=foo2; col2[2]=bar2` here `[1]` would be the line number `NR`. You can also use a multi-dimension array or the array of array to do that. Do a google search you will find some tutorials.
- When you got everything you need, you can start printing.

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

With `bash`, `awk`, `ed` and `column` it's not pretty but it does the job.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mapfile -t passwd < <(
  printf '0a\nUsername:2:UID:GID:5:Home:Shell:/bin/bash\n.\n,p\nQ\n' |
  ed -s /etc/passwd
)

ed -s <(
  printf '%s\n' "${passwd[@]}" |
  awk 'BEGIN { FS=":" ; OFS=" | "
  } /\/bin\/bash$/ {
    print  "| " $1, $3, $4, $6, $7 " |"
  }' | column -t) < <(
    echo '$t$
      $s/|/+/g
      $s/[^+]/-/g
      1t0
      1s/|/+/g
      1s/[^+]/-/g
      3t3
      3s/|/+/g
      3s/[^+]/-/g
      ,p
      Q
  '
)
```

As far as remember just `awk` and `column` and GNU `datamash` can do what the OP's is asking but I can't remember where is the link now.

- Works on GNU `ed` but should work also with the `BSD` variant of `ed`
- Also `mapfile` is a bash4+ feature jfyi.